# MySQL stored procedure return result before end of procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Is it possible to return the result of a select statement in a stored procedure, before the procedure is done running?  For example:

```
Create Procedure 'TestProc'()
Begin

//Do some stuff

Select 'column' from table';

//Do some more stuff

End
```

Is it possible to return the result of the select statement immediately and have the procedure keep doing it's thing afterwords?

Thanks

Comment: No, and the rest of this answer is just to complete the 15 chars minimum requirement.

Answer (score 1):

what kind of stuff are you wanting to keep doing after the select?   Maybe you could insert the select query into a temp table, continue doing other stuff, then finally select at the very end?  The temp table values would still be as if they were returned mid routine but you could still continue doing the "other stuff."

**Edit from below comment:**
To me this should be handled from the application doing the following
-Break the current stored procedure up into 2 parts

1. Call the 1st Insert Stored Procedure from the code that takes the first part of the string and inserts it into the database.  Return the Id to the application
2. The application takes the id it received back, and calls the second stored procedure(time consuming one) and passes 2 parameters.  The id and the rest of the string.
3. The database continues with the rest of the insert while your application continues on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This procedure takes very big deliminated string as a parameter.  In the beginning of the procedure I parse part of the string and do an insert.  After the first insert I do the select in question.  It returns the last_insert_id value of the insert.  This is the only value that the application which called the procedure, is concerned with.  After the select I then parse the remaining section of the string, and run a while loop to insert a lot of inserts.  This takes a little bit of time and causing an issue with the application...

Comment: Yeah I would do that but unfortunately I don't have control over the application it self.  At least not that part of the code...

Answer (score 1):

You can finish the procedure doing this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure(Val INT)
proc:BEGIN

IF Val=5 then
Select ‘Bye’;
LEAVE proc;
END IF;

Select * from myTable t t.Value=Value;

END;
```

Comment: So even after leaving the procedure it is going to keep running your select statement, or a bunch of insert statements in my case?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you haven't actually tried this.

An unbounded `SELECT` statement (i.e, not in a subquery, derived table, or `SELECT ... INTO`) will immedately return the result to the client.

> MySQL supports a very useful extension that enables the use of regular SELECT statements (that is, without using cursors or local variables) inside a stored procedure. The result set of such a query is simply sent directly to the client.
>
> <sup>— http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-routines-syntax.html</sup>

The results are sent to the client as soon as they are available, not after the procedure terminates.  This is easily demonstrated by calling the procedure with the MySQL command line client.

The problem you will have, though, is that your application thread *must* eventually wait for the procedure to terminate, because if it disconnects too soon, the procedure could abort or the application could try to reuse the database connection for a different request before the procedure is done, leading to results that would be unpredictable, at best.

If your application can reliably hold on for the end of the procedure's execution, then this will do what you want; otherwise, you'll need a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Procedure 'TestProc'() Begin

//Do some stuff
Insert into temptable(column)
Select 'column' from table';

//Do some more stuff

End
```

Note : This way you can access values of select from temptable and the procedure will keep on executing the later stuff.

After you accessed the value you can delete it from the table. To add more you can insert some session level identifier for bifurcation.